# JDBC (postgreSql) how to export / import java.sqlTime without milliseconds precision loss

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, time

I'm using JDBC to export data from postgreSql database to text file. I need to export / import all the possible types to String. Most of types serialize perfectly except java.sqlTime. When I create both Time and TimeStamp using SQL NOW() it creates records on my database:

```
time            | timestamp
--------------------------------------------
13:17:03.121719 | 2017-10-13 13:17:03.121719
```

Object time is mapped by JDBC into java.sql.Time. To write it I simply use:

```
String time = value.toString();
```

When I want to map it from text file back to java.sql.Time and import to database I use:

```
java.sql.Time.valueOf(value.toString());
```

It works perfectly with java.sql.TimeStamp, but not with java.sql.Time. After importing to database (using preparedStatement.setTime()) i get:

`13:17:03` instead of `13:17:03.121719`

I tried also export like this:

```
String time = String.valueOf(value.getTime());
```

and import:

```
new java.sql.Time(Long.parseLong(value.toString()));
```

Result is better, but I get:
`13:17:03.121` instead of `13:17:03.121719`

So I'm still losing milliseconds precision. Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Since **now()** returns a **Timestamp**, did you try saving **Time** values as Timestamp (e.g. *preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp)*.

Comment: Consider using `LocalTime` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Time.toString()` returns the value in `hh:mm:ss` format, meaning that any milliseconds are discarded. The milliseconds aren't absent from the object, but they're not visible by default. The `getTime()` method returns the most accurate state of the object, as can be observed from the following code

```
Time t = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()+1345);
System.out.println(t);
System.out.println(new Timestamp(t.getTime()));
```

Note that you still get only millisecond precision.

Your real issue is in exporting the data in **text format** through your own code. Unless there's a valid reason for it, you shouldn't even bother. You can take binary dumps that are a lot easier and accurate, or use any other ready made tools.